# why the distance varies for Google Distance Matrix Api?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-distancematrix-api

We are planning to use Distance matrix API to calculate the shortest distance from a pickup to deliver point and we will charge prices based on the distance. We have noticed the distance returned by google matrix API varies, even though we are not using the departure_time parameter(It should not consider traffic,right?)

What can we do to get a fixed distance or shortest distance? How does the google distance matrix API calculates the distance when the departure date is not added (we dont want to take traffic into account).
Thank you.